# "Break early" if one of GitHub actions fails

Tags: github, github-actions, bitrise, codacy

Our CI setup is currently looking like this on GitHub:

[image]

Usually, first check is finishing much sooner than second check. It can succeed or fail. Is it possible (and if so - how) to "break early" and terminate remaining actions as soon as some action fails?

Comment: Typically, you would at least want to know whether the second one succeeded or failed so you could address both sets of issues at once if necessary.  If you have a particular reason for not doing that, it might help to explain what it is so we could suggest an alternative way to help you achieve your goal.

Comment: Could you please share your workflow? Probably you need the [steps conditions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsif)

Comment: Thank you guys, there is actually no workflow (in a Github actions sense). Codacy and Bitrise are using web hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily but only within a single workflow. If you have multiple workflows.

```
strategy:
  matrix:
    os: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, windows-latest]
  fail-fast: true
```

Comment: Thanks - I can understand this would work if my setup was actually using any yml with github actions - but it's not using any, I believe both Codacy and Bitrise have some webhooks setup and there is no yml file to interact with them.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, at least now, with a combination of some tools/APIs.

1. Listen to step failure

```
    name: Stop Bitrise on Failure
        if: ${{ failure() && steps.demo.conclusion == 'failure' }}
        run: curl ...
```

2. Use Bitrise Abort build curl
   From: [Aborting Builds](https://devcenter.bitrise.io/en/api/triggering-and-aborting-builds.html#aborting-a-build)

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: ACCESS-TOKEN" "https://api.bitrise.io/v0.1/apps/APP-SLUG/builds/BUILD-SLUG/abort" -d "{}"
```

3. Final result

```
    name: Stop Bitrise on Failure
        if: ${{ failure() && steps.demo.conclusion == 'failure' }}
        run: curl -X POST -H "Authorization: ACCESS-TOKEN" "https://api.bitrise.io/v0.1/apps/APP-SLUG/builds/BUILD-SLUG/abort" -d "{}"
```